# $\mathbb{C}_{\exp}$ is not model complete.

Tags: analysis, logic, complex-numbers, model-theory

I am trying to understand the following proof (Proposition 1.1 [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Emarker/eac-fin.pdf)):

> **Proposition**: $\mathbb{C}_{\exp}$ is not model complete.
> **Proof**: If $\mathbb{C}_{\exp}$ is model complete, then every definable set is a projection of
> a closed set. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is locally compact, every definable set is $F_σ$. The same is true for the complement, so every definable set is also $G_δ$. But, since $\mathbb{Z}$
> is definable, $\mathbb{Q}$ is definable and a standard corollary of the Baire Category Theorem tells us that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_δ$.

How can we say that every definable set is $F_σ$?

Here, $\mathbb{C}_{\exp}$ is the field of complex numbers defined in the language of rings with an additional function for exponentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with: every definable set is a projection of a closed set.  [This is given, and not proved here.]

In $\mathbb C$, every closed set is a union of countably many compact sets.  The projection of a compact set is compact.  A compact set is closed.

Thus: a projection of a closed set is a countable union of closed sets.

Conclusion: every definable set is an $F_\sigma$.

Comment: But note: all of this is deduced from the (contrary to fact) hypothesis that $\mathbb C_{\text{exp}}$ is model complete.